# SSL Certificate problem on Amazon AWS Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, acme, aws-acm

My SSL working fine on AWS (https://786times.com). I delete ELB a few days ago,But after this I face SSL issue on my website.Everything looks fine like ec2, cloudfront,hosted zone DNS records,Please give me solution?
I make SSL again through Certificate Manager of AWS using DNS validation method and  include in Cloudfront also.
but still not working SSL with my website.
Any one Guide me.
I am using Wordpress Bitnami.

Thanks
786times.com@gmail.com

I Expect from Technical friends that they reply.

Comment: So your problem was created by deleting your LB - why didn't you restore it then?

Comment: I don't want to use ELB due to high Cost which is nearly $18 per month on aws server. Students can use this site for prepare exams in remote areas of South Asia to enhance knowledge on different subjects.

Comment: Makes sense. Which other approach do you want to use?

Comment: I want without ELB.

Comment: I want without ELB. Christoph Fischer,this website is used to enhance education in remote areas. Please if possible solve me issue

Comment: How I restore ELB... Please Guide

Comment: Please edit your questions with what you really want. Is it a) restoring an previously deleted ELB or b) how to do SSL without an ELB ?

Comment: how to do SSL without an ELB ? Please help me.

Comment: Then your answer can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/947057/install-aws-ssl-certificate-to-ec2-instance-without-load-balancer